# Traversing anchor, unsorted list, and sublist elements with Jquery

Tags: jquery

I'm learning JQuery and I'm trying to understand how to parse an unsorted list.
My script works and it can highlight in yellow sublist (click on "level 2C" and 2d anchor), but i'm unable to highlight only level 3 or only level 4.

Any clue on how to do that ? Thanks.

Here is my code :

```
    <script type="text/javascript" language="JavaScript">
    $(document).ready(function (){

        $(".level2").click(function(){
            $(this).next("ul").css("background", "yellow");
          });

    });
```

```
<div >
  <ul>
    <li ><a class="level1">Level  1</a>
      <ul>
        <li><a class="level2" href="#">Level 2a</a></li>
        <li><a class="level2" href="#">Level 2b</a></li>
        <li><a class="level2">Level 2c</a>
          <ul>
            <li><a class="level3" href="#">Level 3a</a></li>
            <li><a class="level3">Level 3b</a>
              <ul>
                <li><a class="level4">Level 4a</a></li>
                <li><a class="level4">Level 4b</a></li>
              </ul>
            </li>
            <li><a class="level3">Level 3c</a>
              <ul>
                <li><a class="level4">Level 4c</a></li>
                <li><a class="level4">Level 4d</a></li>
              </ul>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </li>
        <li><a class="level2">Level 2d</a>
          <ul>
            <li><a class="level3" href="#">Level 3c</a></li>
            <li><a class="level3">Level 3d</a>
              <ul>
                <li><a class="level4" href="#">Level 4e</a></li>
                <li><a class="level4" href="#">Level 4f</a></li>
              </ul>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Sorry, I'm French !

Comment: 4 is nested in 3 so it's hard to tell what exactly you mean by selecting "only" 3, since by selecting 3 you automatically select 4.

Comment: Hi, Peter. I'm learning so, i try to understand how traversing works. My first idea was to click on one of the "level 2" anchor and highlight all the "level 4" children. But i don't know how to code that I want to reach the next ul next ul.

Answer (score 0):

Assign the handler to the `<a>` elements using the [attribute-starts-with selector](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-starts-with-selector/) where the class name attribute starts with `level`, and then make sure the event doesn't bubble by [calling `e.stopPropagation()`](http://api.jquery.com/event.stoppropagation/).

**Example:** http://jsbin.com/upuho3/3

```
  $("a[class^=level]").click(function( e ){
       $(this).next("ul").css("background", "yellow");
       e.stopPropagation(); 
   });
```

---

**EDIT:** If you want to clear previous selections, you could place and ID on the `<div>` container, and use that [to `.find()`](http://api.jquery.com/find/) the nested `<ul>` elements, and reset them before you select the current.

**Example:** http://jsbin.com/upuho3/4

```
$("a[class^=level]").click(function( e ){
     $('#top').find("ul").css("background", "");
     $(this).next("ul").css("background", "yellow");
     e.stopPropagation();
 });
```

HTML

```
<div id="top">
  <ul>
    <li ><a class="level1">Level  1</a>
     ...
```

I'd suggest using classes with [jQuery's `.addClass()` method](http://api.jquery.com/addclass/) instead of using [the `.css()` method](http://api.jquery.com/css/) though.

---

**EDIT:** `e.stopPropagation()` really shouldn't be necessary since the click event is on the `<a>` element and as such it won't trigger the ancestor `<a>` elements.

Comment: Thanks a lot Patrick, very elegant solution. I'm stuck with this syntax : "a[class^=level]" . Is there a page on the jquery website about ^= ?

Comment: @Jim D - Ah yes, I'm lacking some documentation links in my answer. I'll update. The one you're asking about is [the attribute-starts-with selector](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-starts-with-selector/).

Comment: Very usefull chapter about the attribute. Thank you. I will try now to highlight only the "next ul next ul" (level 2 click highlight children of level 4). Not easy for me.